# WebLogic 10.3.4 wildcard certificate import

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, weblogic, spring-webclient

I have a local environment with WebLogic 10.3.4 and and .ear app deployed on it. This app must communicate with external services via REST APIs. These external services are exposed in https and use wildcard certificates.

I receive the following exceptions when I try to connect to to one of these services.

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://dds-service.domain.com" General SSLEngine problem; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem [...]
[...] Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target [...]
[...] Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

So what I tried in first instance was to open the same url the app tries to connect to in my browser, download its wildcard certificate (.cer Base64 encoded) and with key tool import it into the jvm's trust store that WebLogic loads and looks up when trying to validate a cert. I am sure is the correct one because i imported other certificates that caused the same error and also because of this log

```
<Loading trusted certificates from the jks keystore file C:\WEBLOG~1\wls\JROCKI~1.1-3\jre\lib\security\cacerts.>
```

At this point, I suppose the problem is related to the way I import the wildcard certificate in WebLogic. I tried to look for different ways to do it but, like [this one](https://oraidam.wordpress.com/2016/05/25/weblogic-ssl-wildcard-configuration/), require a .pfx file that is not currently available to me at the moment.

Do I need a .pfx to solve this or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone will ever have the same problem, here is the solution i found: it appears that WLS 10.3.x has issues in trusting certificates wth keys longer than 128 bits, this is what caused the problem in first instance. That said, 2 actions solved my problem

1. -DUseSunHttpHandler=true added as a VM argument in the setDomainEnv script
2. Enable JSSE SSL via WLS adminn console (Environment > Servers > server name > Configuration > SSL > Advanced > check the JSSE SSL box)
3. Click Save, and restart WLS server.